# Unity Touch problem

Tags: unity, movement, gui

Learning from some tutorials. 
Made Swipe touch scene.
Have UI(virtual joystick) on canvas screen overlay. The problem is,when I am rotating character by joystick, my camera rotating too. If I've pressed on my UI, swiping script turning my camera around and I can't move the right way.
How can I solve this problem?
**@Byte56** 
**So your camera is rotating, when you're trying to steer using your on screen joystick?**
***Yes***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, a common solution is to use a global flag. Basically, when your UI accepts input, you set a global flag (something like `UIConsumingInput`) to true. If you have any other inputs, like your camera rotation, you have it test to see if `UIConsumingInput` is set to true, if `UIConsumingInput` is true, you don't process input.

Comment: The problem was with my scene... My changes in scripts were not implemented into the build. Don't know why... Anyway, I made changes that you wrote above earlier and I will mark it as the right answer.